# Edit / Delete classes in external third party library jar files in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

I am using external third party libraries in my project, but the problem I am facing is, two different jar files contains a class with the same name.

**Following are the libs I am using**

- jaxen-1.1-beta-2.jar
- jaxen-core.jar

The above given jar files share a class with the same name called "**DefaultNavigator.class**" so because of this i am getting the following **duplicate class error**.

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/jaxen/DefaultNavigator.class

I need to know whether i can edit/delete unused classes or repeated classes given in the external third party jar files or please guide me whether i can copy only the classes that i required from all the jars and put them up in a single jar file and use. if this is possible please tell me how to do this. I am a beginner to android. Below I am attaching my build.gradle file.

> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx.yyy"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile files('libs/xsdlib-1.5.jar')
compile files('libs/relaxngDatatype-2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.xml.stream.jar')
compile files('libs/pull-parser-2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.xml.bind.jar')
compile files('libs/java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jaxen-core.jar')
compile files('libs/jaxen-dom4j.jar')
compile files('libs/jaxen-1.1-beta-2.jar')

}
```